# Chainlink Keepers. Working once then not

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Hi im having trouble trying to get my auctions automated. Ive had the keeper succesfully resolve a single auction but then it's like im losing my place somehow. I can only get a single auction to resolve via keeper. the uint indexRef is holding int values representing the location of the particular auction we want to handle in the array of mock auctions called autoResolveQ
[Here is the gist](https://gist.github.com/iFrogHop2Worlds/d46a0b926559ca490fa5d8858216ab31#file-auctionimplementation-sol)

```
uint[] public indexRef;
function checkUpkeep(bytes memory /*checkData*/)
    public
    view
    override
    returns (bool upKeepNeeded, bytes memory performData)
{
    bool go = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < int(autoResolveQ.length) ;i++){
        address nft = autoResolveQ[uint256(i)].nft;
        uint256 tokenId = autoResolveQ[uint256(i)].tokenId;
        if(!_onAuction(nft, tokenId))
            go = true;
    } 
    upKeepNeeded = (go);
    performData = bytes(''); //abi.encode(indexRef);
}
event PerformedUPKEEP();
function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /*performData*/) external override {
    //uint[] memory ref = abi.decode(performData, (uint[]));
    //require(address(this).balance >= 0, "Not enough ETH");
    //(bool upKeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
    //require(upKeepNeeded, "No upkeep needed");
    //resolve an auction.
    for(int i = 0; int(i) < int(autoResolveQ.length); i++){
        address nft = autoResolveQ[uint256(i)].nft;
        uint256 tokenId = autoResolveQ[uint256(i)].tokenId;
        if(!_onAuction(nft, tokenId)){
            indexRef.push(uint(i));  
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < int(indexRef.length); i++){
        uint idx = indexRef[uint(i)];
        Auction storage auc = autoResolveQ[idx]; // mock auction holding the id and address
        _End(auc.nft, auc.tokenId);
        autoResolveQ[idx] = autoResolveQ[autoResolveQ.length-1];
        autoResolveQ.pop();
        indexRef[idx] = indexRef[indexRef.length-1];
        indexRef.pop();
    }
    //delete ref;
    emit PerformedUPKEEP(); 
}
```

Comment: what is `checkUpkeep` returning?

Comment: Im just taking some time to work on avalanche hackathon & will be back on this soon
Thx for replying.. Ill update this soon with solution